# What is the cofinality of $([\kappa]^\omega, \subseteq)$?

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, large-cardinals, cardinal-arithmetic

For an uncountable cardinal $\kappa$, we are interested in the least size of a cofinal subset of the partial order  $([\kappa]^\omega, \subseteq)$. It is obvious that this cofinality is at least $\kappa$ and a rather simple induction shows that $cof([\aleph_n]^\omega, \subseteq)=\aleph_n$ for each natural number $n \geq 1$.

**What is known in $ZFC$ for bigger cardinals?**

Also I am intrigued by the following statement made by Alan Dow in *Efimov spaces and the splitting number*, Topology Proc. (2005):

> It is a "large cardinal" hypothesis to assume that there is a cardinal $\kappa$ with uncountable cofinality such that this cofinality is greater than $\kappa$.

**What exactly does he mean by that, and what is a good reference to read about it?**

Comment: Pcf theory. ${}$

Comment: An excellent reference to get started is Eisworth's chapter in the Handbook.

Comment: Do you understand what are large cardinals and what is a large cardinal hypothesis?

Comment: Subsection 3.1 of https://doi.org/10.1016/j.apal.2005.09.012 may be illuminating.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I have seen large cardinals and I have seen large cardinal hypothesis, but I don't know a precise definition of either of those concepts.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think he means the consistency of "there exists a cardinal $\kappa$ with uncountable cofinality so that $cf([\kappa]^\omega, \subseteq) > \kappa$" requires large cardinal axioms.

To motivate this, note that for example if $0^\sharp$ does not exist, then  for any cardinal $\kappa > 2^{\aleph_0}$ of uncountable cofinality we have $cf([\kappa]^\omega, \subseteq) = \kappa$.

In fact one can say more. A related argument is given in Theorem 3.1 of   [Singular cofinality conjecture and a question of Gorelic.](http://math.ipm.ac.ir/~golshani/Papers/On%20a%20question%20of%20Gorelic.pdf)

Comment: How about cardinals below the continuum?

Comment: @Ramiro same same. See the proof of Theorem 3.13(d) of https://doi.org/10.1016/j.apal.2005.09.012

Comment: @saf , so it is correct to say that If there is a $\kappa$ of uncountable cofinality for which $cof([\kappa]^\omega,\subseteq)>\kappa$ then there is an inner model with a measurable cardinal?

Comment: @Ramiro correct.