# Minimum cardinality of a cofinal collection of countable subsets of a set

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, infinite-combinatorics, cardinal-arithmetic

**Setup**

---

Let $X$ be a set of cardinality $\kappa\geq \aleph_0$.

*Edit:*

Based on **Todd Eisworth**'s suggestion:

What is the minimum cardinality of a collection $\hat{X}$ of countable subsets of $X$ such that every countable subset $A \subseteq X$ is contained in some element of $\hat{X}$?

---

Comment: I guess you mean "infinite countable". In ZFC the picture is clear: for $\kappa>\aleph_0$ there're a single orbit. For $\kappa=\aleph_0$, contrary to your claim the orbits are listed in terms of the cardinal of its complement, which is a non-negative integer or $\aleph_0$. I guess this even holds in ZF+DC. If you're really interested in the ZF picture, would you be more explicit?

Comment: Yes I mean "infinite countable".  However, what do you mean by an orbit in this case (the action of the symmetric group on $\mathbb{N}$ on the set of sequences on X)?  In that case, I don't see why there would be a single orbit if $\kappa>\aleph_0$?

Comment: Oh, you're just using a misleading terminology. You're actually counting "infinite countable subsets of $X$" modulo nothing (countable subsets modulo permutation suggest modulo permutations of $X$). That means injective maps from $\mathbf{N}\to X$ modulo precomposition by permutations of $\mathbf{N}$.

Comment: If I understand correctly that you counting infinite countable subsets of $X$, its cardinal is $0$ for $X$ finite and $\kappa^{\aleph_0}$ for $X$ infinite (=$2^{\aleph_0}$ for $X=\aleph_0$, $=\kappa$ for infinite $X=2^\alpha$).

Comment: "non-trivial" means??

Comment: The relation you've got in the question is trivial, as you can always take the union of two countable sets to prove they are equivalent.  It IS sensible to ask about the minimum number of countable subsets of $\kappa$ needed so that any countable subset of $\kappa$ is a subset of the given family.

Comment: @ToddEisworth I incoporated your suggested interpretation of my question.  I think you explained the correct thing I'm looking for..

Comment: You're writing "is in $\hat{X}$" but seem to mean "is a subset of some element of $\hat{X}$", which is drastically different.

Comment: @YCor Yes you're right, but I was worried that such a collection may not exist.  Indeed, I modified the question now.

Comment: It now makes sense. Write $f:\kappa\mapsto f((\kappa)$ this function, so $f(\aleph_0)=1$, and $f(\aleph_1)=\aleph_1)$. In general, for uncountable $\kappa$ one has $\kappa\le f(\kappa)\le\kappa^{\aleph_0}$. I'm guess it's been studied and hope set theory people will provide some feedback.

Comment: If $\kappa\geq 2^{\aleph_0}$ then $f(\kappa)=\kappa^{\aleph_0}$. My guess is that for $\kappa<2^{\aleph_0}$ things could be weird.

Comment: We have $f(\aleph_{\alpha+1})=\max(f(\aleph_{\alpha}),\aleph_{\alpha+1})$. In particular, $f(\aleph_n)=\aleph_n$ for all $n$. Also, for $\lambda$ limit of uncountable cofinality, $f(\aleph_\lambda)=\sup_{\alpha<\lambda}f(\aleph_\alpha)$. I have no idea about $f(\aleph_\omega)$.

Comment: Clearly $f(\aleph_n)=\aleph_n$ for $n>0$, and for limit cardinals $\kappa$ of uncountable cofinality one has  $f(\kappa) = \sup(f(i):i<\kappa)$.   Also, in analogy with Hausdorff's successor formula, $f(\kappa^+)=\max(f(\kappa), \kappa^+)$.  The interesting question is when $\kappa$ has countable cofinality, and Shelah's pcf theory has something to say about this. It is clear that $\kappa^{\aleph_0} = f(\kappa) \cdot 2^ {\aleph_0}$, so the number $f(\kappa)$ is sometimes seen as "more interesting that $\kappa^{\aleph_0}$, as it helps to separate the "noise" (continuum) from the information.

Comment: I see now that my comment repeats most of  @YCor 's comment.

Comment: Both these comments are very helpful, but since my set-theory is not my strongest field, would it be possible to post some references/ more details on the computation $f(\aleph_n)=\aleph_n\, n>0$ etc..

Comment: I don't see where it's been mentioned yet that $f(\kappa)$ always has uncountable cofinality.  So $f(\aleph_\omega)\gt\aleph_\omega$. Which must be like $2+2=4$ to the set theorists but may be worth pointing out to the general public.

Comment: @bof Would it be possible to mention some details since this is far from obvious for a non-set-theorist such as myself

Comment: Suppose $f(\kappa)=\lambda=\sum_{n\in\omega}\lambda_n$ with $\lambda_n\lt\lambda$. Let $\hat X$ be a cofinal family of countable subsets of $\kappa$ with $|\hat X|=\lambda$. Write $\hat X=\bigcup_{n\in\omega}\hat X_n$ where $|\hat X_n|=\lambda_n\lt\lambda$. For each $n$ choose a countable set $A_n$ contained in no element of $\hat X_n$; then $\bigcup_nA_n$ is a countable set contained in no element of $\hat X$. Contradiction.

Comment: @bof I would hapilly accept this as an answer, hapilly, if you could add a couple references for a non-expert such as myself.

Comment: @Rahman.M By $\operatorname{cof}([\lambda^+],\subseteq)=\lambda^{\aleph_0}$ did you mean $\operatorname{cof}([\lambda^+]^\omega,\subseteq)=\lambda^{\aleph_0}$? If so, how do you prove that? We know that $\operatorname{cof}([\lambda^+]^\omega,\subseteq)=\operatorname{cof}([\lambda]^\omega,\subseteq)$ when $\lambda$ is singular and of countable cofinality..

Comment: @Rahman.M Of course we are interested in the case where $2^{\aleph_0}\gt\lambda^+$.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/q/287888/1783

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it is stated in the comments, the question is about the cofinality of $([\lambda]^{\aleph_0}, \subseteq)$.

The following definition is due to Shelah:

$
cov(\lambda, \mu, \theta, \sigma)=min\{|P|: P$ is a family of subsets of $\lambda$ each of size $< \mu$ such that for every $a \subseteq \lambda, |a|<\theta$, for some $\alpha < \sigma$ and $A_i \in P,$ for $i<\alpha,$ we have $a \subseteq \bigcup_{i<\alpha}A_i   \}$.

It is easily sean that

1-$cf([\lambda]^{\aleph_0}, \subseteq)=cov(\lambda, \aleph_1, \aleph_1, 2)$.

By a theorem of Shelah (see [Sh: 355],  $\aleph _{\omega +1}$ has a Jonsson Algebra, see also [Analytic guides and updates for cardinal arithmetic](https://shelah.logic.at/v1/E12.pdf) page 23)

2-$\lambda^{\aleph_0}=cov(\lambda, \aleph_1, \aleph_1, 2)+ 2^{\aleph_0}$.

Note that in particular, if $\lambda^{\aleph_0} > 2^{\aleph_0}$, then

$cf([\lambda]^{\aleph_0}, \subseteq)=\lambda^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: (1) is just the definition of "cov" with those particular parameters, so this is just standard cardinal arithmetic, i.e., no need to quote Shelah here!

Comment: The notation you are using is probably impenetrable for someone asking the question. Would you mind adding a reference or some definitions?

Comment: (2) is more or less obvious (see the comment by Goldstern below the question). Shelah lists this as an "observation" in [Sh355](https://shelah.logic.at/files/94577/355.pdf) (p. 85). Also a minor point: $\lambda\geq 2^{\aleph_0}$ suffices for the final conclusion--the point being that we can include $\lambda=2^{\aleph_0}$. (not a big deal).

Comment: Actually "$\lambda^+\geq 2^{\aleph_0}$" is enough for the last bit (as in bof's comment).

Comment: Actually yes...since I'm not  set-theorist the "it is easily seen" is prettttttttty far from even seeable...               Could you add some details please?